# Issues with starting back camera on Chrome on Android (facingMode: environment)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, camera, android-camera, getusermedia

I have a little web app that runs nicely on iOS on Safari. It scans QR codes and does an audio sync.

However, if I try to load up the back camera on Chrome on my Samsung S7 phone, it gives me the following error:

DOMException: Could not start video source

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
const constraints = {

    video: {facingMode: {exact: "environment"},
};

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(stream => {
        debug( "Got userMedia");
        state.stream = stream;

        if ("srcObject" in components.video) {
            components.video.srcObject = stream;
        } else {
            // Avoid using this in new browsers
            components.video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }

        //components.video.srcObject = state.stream;
        components.video.play();

    }, function (err) {
        console.error(err);
        debug( "Error - " + err.message);
    });
```

I simply cannot find a solution for this. It seems fine on newer devices and even works on Chrome on a new iPhone 12. But it seems to be a common issue on older devices.

Any solutions?

Comment: Hit my cheezy diagnostic website https://lit-mesa-75588.herokuapp.com/ with your device, click the Gather button, then grant permission for it to use your cameras and microphone.  Then click the View My Results button and you'll get a bunch of JSON containing descriptions of the media capabilities of your device.  You *may* have to specify the camera you want by name, or you may have an older Android/Chrome version on there that handles .`.getUserMedia()` in some idiosyncratic way. And, try https://webrtc.github.io/samples/ with your device.